# Trying to find the index of the last uppercase char using regex

Tags: java, regex, char, indexof, lastindexof

I need a little bit of help trying to find the last index of the last uppercase char in the string. I have been using regex to do so. However it keeps returning -1 instead of the index of B which is 7.

The code is highlighted below

```java
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String  s2 = "A3S4AA3B3";
        int lastElementIndex = s2.lastIndexOf("[A-Z]");
        System.out.println(lastElementIndex);
    }
}
```

Does anyone have any recommendation on how to fix the issue?

Kind regards.

Comment: `String#lastIndexOf` accepts a string and not a regex.

Comment: That comment is relevant, but does not answer the OP's question, which I would rewrite as "is there an equivalent to `lastIndexOf` that accepts a regular expression?"

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try the regex `[A-Z][^A-Z]*$` :

```
String  s2 = "A3S4AA3B3";
Matcher m = Pattern.compile("[A-Z][^A-Z]*$").matcher(s2);
if(m.find()) {
    System.out.println("last index: " + m.start());
}
```

Output:

```
last index: 7
```

About the regex:

- `[A-Z]` : uppercase letter
- `[^A-Z]*` : `^` means negation, may contain other chars `*` zero or more times
- `$` : end of line

Answer (score 2):

You can get index of last uppercase letter as below

```
int count = 0;
int lastIndex = -1;
for (char c : s2.toCharArray()) {
       count++;  
    if (Character.isUpperCase(c)) {
       lastIndex = count;

    }
}
```

Comment: Starting from the end reduces the iterations.

Comment: Thankyou mate this is it

Comment: sanjeevRm how do i get only the last  iterations

Comment: as suggested, to get last iterations, if you iterate array in reverse order that is `from last index` first matching letter will be your element